# Julia pandas syntax select values from conditional

Tags: pandas, syntax, julia

In pandas for Python if I have a DataFrame with n columns and I want to keep the rows that satisfies some conditional in a specific column I just type: 

`df[df.column1 > 0]`

I couldn't find the correct syntax to do this in Julia pandas.

Comment: bdw it is not "Julia pandas". pandas is the name of a library in Python that implements dataframe (tabular) data structure and related API. Julia DataFrames library has the same objective, but it is not a wrap of Python pandas, it is a completely independent project, although it tries to keep a similar API when possible (and hopefully in a more consistent way).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need:

```
df[df[:column1] .> 0, :]
```

Or:

```
query(df, :(column1>0))
```

Answer (score 2):

From the DataFrame section of the "[Julia language: a concise tutorial](https://sylvaticus.gitbooks.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/content/)":

#### Filter

- Filter by value, based on a field being in a list of values: `df[indexin(df[:colour], ["blue","green"]) .> 0, :]`
- Alternative using list comprehension: `df[ [i in ["blue","green"] for i in df[:colour]], :]`
- Combined boolean selection: `df[(indexin(df[:colour], ["blue","green"]) .> 0) .& (df[:shape] .== "triangle"), :]` (the dot is needed to vectorize the operation). Note the usage of the bitwise and (single) ampersand.
- Filter using `@where` (`DataFrameMeta` package): `@where(df, :x .> 2, :y .== "a") # the two expressions are "and-ed"`. If the column name is stored in a variable, you need to wrap it using the `_I_()` function, e.g. `col = Symbol("x"); @where(df, _I_(col) .> 2)`
- Change a single value by filtering columns: `df[ (df[:product] .== "hardWSawnW") .& (df[:year] .== 2010) , :consumption] = 200`
- Filter based on initial pattern: `filteredDf = df[startswith.(df[:field],pattern),:]`